# Force Java/Eclipse to provide more information in a stack trace

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

While debugging a plugin in Eclipse, I see this exception:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.monitoring 2 0 2016-02-16 10:43:21.573
!MESSAGE UI freeze of 0.63s at 10:43:20.943
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui.monitoring 1 0 2016-02-16 10:43:21.573
!MESSAGE Sample at 10:43:21.278 (+0.335s)
Thread 'main' tid=1 (RUNNABLE)
!STACK 0
java.lang.Exception: Stack Trace
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:56)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:686)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:420)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.ZipBundleEntry$ZipBundleEntryInputStream.read(ZipBundleEntry.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.StorageUtil.getBytes(StorageUtil.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storage.bundlefile.BundleEntry.getBytes(BundleEntry.java:94)`
    ...
```

Given the nature of the code and the rest of the stack trace, 
I suspect Eclipse is having trouble reading a JAR archive on the file system.
There are many of these and I'd like to know which one.
However the exception doesn't offer me that information.
This all happens inside Eclipse and JDK code (i.e. hasn't hit my plugin
yet.)

Is there some clever way I can hook into the relevant code to see which file it's trying to read and failing? I've set breakpoints at various locations. However it appears that Eclipse uses this same code to load hundreds of files or more, so clicking through each one is extremely tedious.

Comment: That doesn't actually look like a failure. It looks like you have UI responsiveness monitoring active and it has seen a 0.63s delay while a jar is being loaded (probably a plugin), nothing has actually gone wrong.

Comment: Be that as it may, the question still stands. Is there some way to hook in so I can see where this is occurring?

Answer (score 4):

If you start Eclipse specifying `-debug <path of debug file>` on the command (or in the eclipse.ini) you can enable many debug options by setting values in the debug file.

Many of the core Eclipse plugins have long lists of things you can turn on. For the `org.eclipse.osgi` plugin shown in your log the options are:

```
#### Debugging options for org.eclipse.osgi

# Turn on general debugging for org.eclipse.osgi
org.eclipse.osgi/debug=false
# Prints out location debug information
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/location = false
# Prints out class loading debug information
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/loader=false
# Prints out event (FrameworkEvent/BundleEvent/ServiceEvent) and listener debug information
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/events=false
# Prints out OSGi service debug information (registration/getting/ungetting etc.)
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/services=false
# Prints out bundle manifest parsing debug information
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/manifest=false
# Prints out LDAP filter debug information
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/filter=false
# Prints out security (PermissionAdmin service) debug information
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/security=false
# Prints out start level service debug information
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/startlevel=false
# Prints out package admin service debug information
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/packageadmin=false
# Prints out timing information for bundle activation
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/bundleTime=false
# Debug the loading of message bundles
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/messageBundles=false
# Debug the object pool additions
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/objectPool/adds=false
# Debug the object pool duplications
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/objectPool/dups=false
# Debug the caching of bundle headers
org.eclipse.osgi/debug/cachedmanifest = false

# Eclipse adaptor options
org.eclipse.osgi/eclipseadaptor/debug = false
org.eclipse.osgi/eclipseadaptor/debug/platformadmin=false
org.eclipse.osgi/eclipseadaptor/debug/platformadmin/resolver=false
org.eclipse.osgi/eclipseadaptor/converter/debug = false

### OSGi resolver options
# General debug option for the resolver. Enabling this option is equivalent to 
# enabling all other resolver debug options. 
org.eclipse.osgi/resolver = false
# Displays the current root bundle which is being resolved
org.eclipse.osgi/resolver/roots=false
# Displays information about matching capabilities returned to the resolver and
# why any were filtered out.
org.eclipse.osgi/resolver/providers = false
# Displays information about capabilities or resources that were filtered by 
# resolver hooks.
org.eclipse.osgi/resolver/hooks = false
# Displays information about uses constraint violations.
org.eclipse.osgi/resolver/uses = false
# Displays wiring information after the resolve process completes.
org.eclipse.osgi/resolver/wiring = false
# Displays the resolution report information.
org.eclipse.osgi/resolver/report = false


#### Monitoring settings

# monitor eager bundle activation
org.eclipse.osgi/monitor/activation=false
# monitor lazy bundle activation
org.eclipse.osgi/monitor/lazy=false
```

To enable any of the options you must always set

```
org.eclipse.osgi/debug=true
```

and then set the other options you want to `true`

Recent releases of Eclipse also provide the 'General > Tracing' page in the Preferences to set these values.

Comment: Following above I am getting logs in CMD, but I want to save those logs in file. Is there any option to save those logs to a file by editing in the config.ini file?

Comment: @vipulkumawat The new 'General > Tracing' page in the 'Preferences' has options for saving to disk.

Comment: I've a RCP application, I'm starting it with target set to -debug -data >trace.log.  I need to store all trace logging in trace.log. I have added this options to config.ini -> org.eclipse.osgi/debug/loader=true, org.eclipse.osgi/trace/classLoading=true . I cannot save the logs using 'Tracing' page because all the classes are loaded during the application being up. -debug -data >trace.log is not saving the logs to the file.

Comment: Ask a new question, this is not suitable for comments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051981/save-rcp-based-applications-forced-generated-trace-logs-to-a-file Please help me here!